# Unable to install Microsoft office 2016 professional plus

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

I have windows 10 anniversary. When i try to install Microsoft office professional plus 2016 it shows the following error.

Error comes while installing microsoft office 2016

[image]

I have restarted my Computer as advised but no luck :(

Comment: Have you actually rebooted as advised? If so, put this in the question too.

Comment: After restart also the same problem persists?

Comment: yes, after restart same problem persists.

Comment: did you run the setup as administrator?

Comment: Yes, even i run the setup in windows 7 compatibility mode.

Comment: Strange thing it got installed in windows 7 service pack 1. but it is not installing on windows 10 anniversary (14393.447)

Comment: @john - I had no problem installing it.  Can you provide us the installation log file?

Comment: look in Eventlog if you see some details about the failure

Answer (score 1):

1. install takeownership software.
2. run powershell
3. paste
   `C:\Windows\System32\takeown.exe  /F C:\ProgramData /R /A`
   in powershell and press enter.

Finish. Please wait for a long time for process all files and folders
then install the office or another software that you can not install them.

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar problem where a Office Professional Plus 2016 32-bit version has failed to install and is still unresolved. Here are my steps and the additional links from Microsoft which may work for you (but which have still not resolved my own problem)

#### Office 2016 Installation problem

Installing on a Windows 10 Desktop 8gm Rm running Office 2010 32-bit.

Microsoft advised us to first uninstall our old Office 2010 before installing the new Office 2016 program. Our Office 2010 had run well for 6 years, but that is when the installation problem began.

When trying to install the OFFICE 2016 32-bit package, it quickly stops with the following error:

```
MICROSOFT PROFESSIONAL PLUS 2016 ENCOUNTERED AN ERROR DURING SETUP
```

When clearing that error, it always shows second error:

```
MICROSOFT SETUP BOOTSTRAPPER HAS STOPPED WORKING
```

We researched blogs and found this problem to be very common whenever an older Office version was uninstalled prior to installing Office 2016, and we followed all the following suggestions (*with full reboots each time*).

1. RAN SFC on drive C: and found no errors.
2. Ran RUN %ProgramData% and renamed Office.help to Office.Help.Old
3. Ran the MS Program Install and Uninstall Troubleshooter.
4. Ran a Clean Boot.
5. Ran Control Panel - in startup found Windows Installer was on and set for Manual.
6. Went back to VLSC site 6 more times and downloaded a fresh Office 2016 (32-bit version) in case any files were corrupt, but I still got the same install messages.

Below are links to Microsoft that have worked for some, but not all, users. I believe Using Windows 10 UNIVSTALL  (before) running the Office 2016 ISO file either removes an important registry entry, or inserts one that causes the new install to fail. Hopefully one of these will help you.

#### Microsoft Links

- [Error 1401, 1402 or 1406 when you install an Office program or open an Office program or document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/838687/error-1401,-1402-or-1406-when-you-install-an-office-program-or-open-an-office-program-or-document)
- [Microsoft Setup Bootstrapper has stopped working](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_install-mso_winother/microsoft-setup-bootstrapper-has-stopped-working/7cd66fa9-a1f3-4f5d-95aa-999b834d6cea)

Comment: nothing worked. I tried all your steps and followed the links but the result is same. going to remove windows 10 itself